# NSRegularExpression not working

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa, nsregularexpression

I'm try to parse a photo id out of a facebook url, e.g.,

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=267217740038587&set=a.207272412699787.48907.100002510899673&type=1

My regex is `@"https?:\/\/(www\.)?facebook\.com\/photo\.php\?fbid=([0-9]+)"`

I tested this with an external tool `RegExhibit` - http://homepage.mac.com/roger_jolly/software/ and it seems to work fine.

However it does not work in XCode. I tried to debug and the problem seems to be the `\?` after  `photo\.php`. When I change it to

`@"https?:\/\/(www\.)?facebook\.com\/photo\.php.fbid=([0-9]+)"` (notice I change `\?` to `.`)

it works perfectly.

While this is acceptable I would like to know why `\?` doesn't work here. Any expert? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure, but perhaps the back slashes `\` are escaping the relevant following character in the NSString itself when it is parsed. For instance,

```
NSLog(@"https?:\/\/(www\.)?facebook\.com\/photo\.php\?fbid=([0-9]+)");
```

actually prints `https?://(www.)?facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=([0-9]+)` which if then treated as its own regex would execute the way you describe it (and does execute semi-properly if you replace the `?` with a `.`)

So, I'm guessing for it to work properly, you'd need `@"https?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?facebook\\.com\\/photo\\.php\\?fbid=([0-9]+)"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
NSString *query = @"parameter=2&secondparameter=3"; // replace this with [url query];
NSArray *components = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (NSString *component in components) {
    [parameters setObject:[[component componentsSeparatedByString:@"="] objectAtIndex:0] forKey:[[component componentsSeparatedByString:@"="] objectAtIndex:1]];
}
```

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this option. Like I said, the modified regex works just fine, but I want to understand why the original regex fails. Thanks!